# Performance properties of time-series operations in R at scale (mainly xts and data.table)

Tags: r, time-series, data.table, xts, quantmod

I am undertaking a new project encompassing large time-series datasets from which dependent calculations are fed into a `shiny` application. As such, efficiency is of interest to me. The operations are typically restricted to elementary period conversions and subsequent summary statistics for risk metrics.

I am investigating which library/approach to build the calculation scripts with. At present, I am OK with `xts` and `data.table`. Although I can resort to libraries as `quantmod` and `TTR`, I am hesitant to deploy blackbox functions in production and would prefer to maintain full traceability.

Thus far, I have carried out the following benchmarking exercise in which a `data.frame` of daily prices is converted into monthly returns. The packages used thus far are `xts`, `data.table` and `quantmod` (as reference). The code is pasted below but can also be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/griipen/TSBenchmark).

**Benchmark Code**

```
# Simple return exercise: Daily Prices to Monthly Returns
# Input: Nx2 data.frame with columns (N days, price) 
# Output: Mx2 object with columns (M months, return)
# Three different functions: 1. xts, 2. data.table, 3. quantmod

rm(list = ls()); gc()

library(data.table) 
library(zoo)
library(xts)
library(ggplot2)
library(quantmod)

# Asset params
spot = 100
r = 0.01
sigma = 0.02
N = 1e5

# Input data: Nx2 data.frame (date, price)
pmat = data.frame( 
    date = seq.Date(as.Date('1970-01-01'), by = 1, length.out = N),
    price = spot * exp(cumsum((r - 0.5 * sigma**2) * 1/N + (sigma * (sqrt(1/N)) * rnorm(N, mean = 0, sd = 1))))
)

# Output functions

      # 1. xts standalone 
      xtsfun = function(mat){
        xtsdf = as.xts(mat[, 2], order.by = mat[, 1])
        eom_prices = to.monthly(xtsdf)[, 4]
        mret = eom_prices/lag.xts(eom_prices) - 1; mret[1] = eom_prices[1]/xtsdf[1] - 1
        mret
      }
      
      # 2. data.table standalone 
      dtfun = function(mat){
        dt = setNames(as.data.table(mat), c('V1', 'V2'))
        dt[, .(EOM = last(V2)), .(Month = as.yearmon(V1))][, .(Month, Return = EOM/shift(EOM, fill = first(mat[, 2])) - 1)]
      }
      
      # 3. quantmod (black box library)
      qmfun = function(mat){
        qmdf = as.xts(mat[, 2], order.by = mat[, 1])
        monthlyReturn(qmdf)
      }

# Check 1 == 2 == 3:
all.equal(
    unlist(dtfun(pmat[1:1000,])[, Return]),
    as.numeric(xtsfun(pmat[1:1000,])),
    as.numeric(qmfun(pmat[1:1000,])),
    scale = NULL
)
    
# Benchmark
library(microbenchmark)
gc()

mbm = microbenchmark(
  xts = xtsfun(pmat),
  data.table = dtfun(pmat),
  quantmod = qmfun(pmat),
  times = 50
)

mbm
```

**Results**

For `N = 1e5`, the three approaches perform similarly:

```
Unit: milliseconds
       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
        xts 20.62520 22.93372 25.14445 23.84235 27.25468  39.29402    50
 data.table 21.23984 22.29121 27.28266 24.05491 26.25416  98.35812    50
   quantmod 14.21228 16.71663 19.54709 17.19368 19.38106 102.56189    50
```

However, for `N = 1e6` I observe a substantial performance divergence for `data.table`:

```
Unit: milliseconds
       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
        xts  296.8969  380.7494  408.7696  397.4292  431.1306  759.7227    50
 data.table 1562.3613 1637.8787 1669.8513 1651.4729 1688.2312 1969.4942    50
   quantmod  144.1901  244.2427  278.7676  268.4302  331.4777  418.7951    50
```

I am very curious as to what drives this result, particularly since `data.table` normally excels at large `N`. Of course, `dtfun` could just be poorly written (and I very much appreciate any code improvements), but I achieve similar results using other approaches including self-joins on EOM dates and `cumprod` on daily returns.

Do `xts` and/or `quantmod` benefit from any internal `rcpp` or eqv calls that improves their performance at scale? Lastly, if you are aware of any other competitive standalone solution (`base`?, `dplyr`?) for large-scale TS, I am all ears.

Comment: Bottleneck AFAIK is rounding Date. `as.yearmon` uses `POSIXlt`, data.table's `mday` uses POSIXlt. POSIXlt is inefficient. data.table's `round.IDate` uses slow `ISOdate`. There is pending request for improvement: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4335

Comment: @jangorecki Thanks! Any ideas for a temporary workaround prior to any improvement of date handling? I tried keying using `.(year(V1), month(V1))` instead of `as.yearmon(V1)` and it yields similar results.

Comment: see source of `year` and `month` and you will understand

Comment: @jangorecki cheers.

Comment: @JDG can you please answer this question yourself, with what you learned from the discussion on Twitter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer resides in `data.table`'s `date` handling. In essence, it employs the `ISOdate` format which is comparatively slow. When imposing integer-based `date`-grouping instead, the results shift in the favor of `data.table`.

I have updated the [TSBenchmark](https://github.com/griipen/TSBenchmark) repository using updated solutions for `xts` and `data.table`. I much appreciate the improvements provided by [Joshua Ulrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271616/joshua-ulrich) and [Matt Dowle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403310/matt-dowle) who deserve full credit.